# XML layout changes are not applied without a full project clean

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, code-generation, android-viewbinding

Any changes in static resources files are not applied until I make a full clean on the project and rebuild.
Should I do changes to a layout, dimens, drawable it doesn't matter. Nothing is changed. (But changes are properly displayed on the preview)

It worked alright before and I don't know what changed... updating the studio to Arctic Fox didn't help.

It also works alright on a new project, so it's the problem in my current one.
Removing the project and cloning it again does not help (my teammate also has the same problem)

Comment: Create a new project in AS and enable `ViewBinding`, create a button & replicate this issue ... check if this happens with the new project too?

Comment: @SomeshKumar no, it does not.
I also tried to update gradle version to 7.0.2 w/ plugin 7.0.0. Also didn't help.

Comment: Described build behaviour looks very similar to the behaviour of app with some errors in resources. Are you 100% sure that you do not have any errors in resources? It could be small mistake in layout that does not give compilation error, but breaks resources indexing.

Comment: @redlabrat is there any way to check if there is an error? like logs or a lint command?

Comment: Have you tried `gradlew build --stacktrace`?

Comment: And maybe this [lint help](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating to the latest version of Android Gradle Plugin? If it's out of date it's possible you ran into a bug, and since it's happening with you and your coworker, I would start by making sure you're on the latest version.

Not sure this would matter or not, but you should check to see if any files from `.idea/` are added to `.gitignore` that shouldn't be there. Tthere could be some project conflicts occurring because of files not meant to be in version control.

Check out https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/androidstudio for the optimal `.gitignore` for Android Studio.

Comment: No, as I said in the comment I tried to update gradle version to 7.0.2 w/ plugin 7.0.0. Also didn't help.
I will double check the .gitignore though